# Azure app service (ASE) SQL Azure connection

Tags: sql, azure, web-applications, ase

I have an app service located inside the app service environment(ASE). I have a virtual network which I have put ASE into the subnet in the Vnet.

What I am trying to do is, I am trying to connect SQL Azure endpoint which is not in Vnet or my azure tenant. ASE has an outbound IP address and when I try to tcpping to azure SQL endpoint, it is responding me without any issue.

The problem is when I try to connect SQL endpoint inside the application, I am getting "Cannot open server" error. It usually happens when there is firewall in SQL Azure endpoint. I have checked log analytics (in target SQL endpoint) and saw my app connection is blocked but when I check the client IP, it shows me private IP of ASE. I really don't understand how it can be possible? I would see my public ip in there, since ASE is external ASE.

Do you have any idea how that can be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled the [virtual network service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) for `Microsoft.Sql` in the ASE subnet, When you connect to your Azure SQL server with service endpoints turned on, the source IP of SQL connections will switch to the **private IP space** of your VNet.

If so, you need to allow the given VNet/subnet by specifying it in the VNet firewall rules of the SQL server. If you do not want to use a virtual network service endpoint, you can whitelist the outbound IP address of the application in the firewall of the SQL server.
[image]

For more information, you could read the [blog1](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/) and [blog2](https://roykim.ca/2018/01/27/app-service-environment-with-app-service-and-azure-sql-using-virtual-network-service-endpoints/).